# Writing a Regex to extract information in Java

Tags: java, regex

I have following two texts.

1) `v1.0 - 80 s200 + 2013-10-17T05:59:59-0700 1TZY6R5HERP7SJRRYDYV 69.71.202.109 7802 41587 495307 30595 HTTP/1.1 POST /gp/ppd`

2) `access-1080.2013-10-17-05.us-online-cpp-portlet-live-1d-i-752c3b12.us-east-1.phnew.com.gz`

I need to get this data from them 
From the first Regex I need :- `1TZY6R5HERP7SJRRYDYV` .Lets call this `accessId`. This is always made up of 20 characters and is combination of digits from 0-9 and upperCase alphabets [A-Z]

I tried using `[A-Z0-9]{20}` with no luck.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile([A-Z0-9]{20});  
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
```

Also I am in search of a java API that matches the pattern and if it matches gives me the pattern as a result

From the second I need `us-online-cpp-portlet-live-1d-i-752c3b12.us-east-1.phnew.com` . I am having a hard time cracking this.

Any help would be useful.

Comment: What is the output for the first pattern? And what kind of difficulties are you facing with the second one? It's hard to create a regex when we don't really know, what characteristics the second example needs, to be matched by the regex.

Comment: What are the rules for the second string you want to extract ?

Comment: The `[A-Z0-9]{20}' looks like it's working for me in testing.  Does the Pattern need to be in quotes?

Comment: The second part of the question probably needs more information.  An example might be that it always starts with "us-" or something similar.  A useful page:http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code - for instance the lack of double quotes in the `Pattern` initialization.

Here's an example of what you're looking for:

```
// text for 1st pattern
String text1 = "v1.0 - 80 s200 + 2013-10-17T05:59:59-0700 1TZY6R5HERP7SJRRYDYV 69.71.202.109 7802 41587 495307 30595 HTTP/1.1 POST /gp/ppd";
// text for 2nd pattern
String text2 = "access-1080.2013-10-17-05.us-online-cpp-portlet-live-1d-i-752c3b12.us-east-1.phnew.com.gz";
// 1st pattern - note that the "word" boundary separators are useless here, 
// but they might come in handy if you had alphanumeric Strings longer than 20 characters
Pattern accessIdPattern = Pattern.compile("\\b[A-Z0-9]{20}\\b");
Matcher m = accessIdPattern.matcher(text1);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
// this is trickier. I assume for your 2nd pattern you want something delimited on the
// left by a dot and starting with 2 lowercase characters, followed by a hyphen, 
// followed by a number of alnums, followed by ".com"
Pattern otherThingie = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\.)[a-z]{2}-[a-z0-9\\-.]+\\.com");
m = otherThingie.matcher(text2);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Output:

```
1TZY6R5HERP7SJRRYDYV
us-online-cpp-portlet-live-1d-i-752c3b12.us-east-1.phnew.com
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to call `Matcher#find()` followed by `Matcher#group()` to get matched result:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z0-9]{20}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
String accessId = null;
if (m.find())
   accessId = m.group();
```